# How can an odd function have a Fourier coefficient $b_n$ be $0$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-series

I'm trying to calculate Fourier coefficient $b_n$ of this periodic function:

[image: Function]

I choose this subintervals:

$$f(t)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             -A &   if  & \frac{-T}{4} \leq t < 0\\
             A &  if & 0 \leq t < \frac{T}{4}\\
             0 &  if & \frac{T}{4} \leq t < \frac{3T}{4}
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

For calculate $b_n$

$$b_n = \frac{2}{T}\left(\int_{\frac{-T}{4}}^0 -A * \sin(nwt) dt + \int_{0}^{\frac{T}{4}} A * \sin(nwt) dt\right)$$

I try to calculate it manually and always I get $0$, and I think thay this is imposible because is an odd function, also if I put this formula in [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2Ft0*%5Bintegrate%20%5BA*sin(n*%20(2*pi)%2Ft%20*%20t),%20%7Bt,%200,%20t0%2F4%7D%20%5D%20%2Bintegrate%20%5B-A%20*%20sin(n*%20(2*pi)%2Ft%20*%20t),%20%7Bt,%20(3t0)%2F4,%20t0%7D%5D%5D) and I get the same, how it's that posible?

Comment: Few notes. It best to integrate from $0$ to $T$ instead of from $-T/4$ to $3T/4$ - just makes it simpler not to miss out on terms. Secondly, the equation you are showing us should have $b_n$ on the LHS, instead of $x(t)$. Lastly please write out what $\omega$ is and how you try to do the integral because you input wrong things in wolfram. (You input $\omega = 2 \pi /t$ and then multiply it with $t$ so that gives you $2 \pi$ and thus you integrate over 0.)

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk My $w = 2\pi f$ and $f=\frac{1}{T}$ so $w  = \frac{2\pi}{T}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put incorrectly the variables in the wolfram input and the limits,

$w = \frac{2\pi}{t}$ should be $w = \frac{2\pi}{t0}$

this is the correct answer [formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2Ft0*%5Bintegrate%20%5B-A*sin(n*%20(2*pi)%2Ft0%20*%20t),%20%7Bt,%20-t0%2F4,%200%7D%20%5D%20%2Bintegrate%20%5BA%20*%20sin(n*%20(2*pi)%2Ft0%20*%20t),%20%7Bt,%200,%20t0%2F4%7D%5D%5D)

Also, this is the Fourier result [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sum%20((4%20Pi%20Sin%5B(n%20Pi)%2F4%5D%5E2)%2F(n%20Pi)%20*%20Sin(nx),%20n%3D1%20to%20100)

Answer (score 0):

No, $b_n$ isn't $0$. And Wolfram Alpha confirms that. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%5B%E2%88%92A%E2%88%97sin(nwt),%7Bt,-T%2F4,0%7D%5D%2BInt%5BA%E2%88%97sin(nwt),%7Bt,0,T%2F4%7D%5D) is the result:

$$
\frac{4A}{n\omega}\sin^2\left(\frac{nT\omega}{8}\right).
$$

Analitacally, take the first integral:

$$
\int_{-T/4}^0 -A\sin(n\omega t)dt = -\int_0^{-T/4} -A\sin(n\omega t)dt = \int_0^{-T/4}A\sin(n \omega t)dt.
$$

Now make the change $t\rightarrow -s$: $dt\rightarrow ds$ and the limits are $0$ and $T/4$. So

$$
\int_0^{T/4} A\sin(-n\omega s)(-ds) = \int_0^{T/4} (-1)^2 A\sin(n\omega s)ds = \int_0^{T/4} A\sin(n\omega s)ds.
$$

Thus

$$
b_n = \frac{4}{T} \int_0^{T/4} A\sin(n\omega t)dt = \frac{4A}{n\omega}\sin^2\left(\frac{nT\omega}{8}\right).
$$